# Array Index out of bounds when reading from CSV file

Tags: java, csv, exception, buffered, reader

I'm trying to read a CSV file using a `BufferedReader`, but for some reason I get an out of bounds exception after 7 rows. I tried this exact algo on another CSV file (30 rows) and it worked fine. [Here](http://www.filedropper.com/database-spells) is the CSV file in question.

```
    String spellPath = "file path is here";

    FileReader y = new FileReader(spellPath);
    BufferedReader x = new BufferedReader(y);
    ArrayList<Card> ArrayList = new ArrayList<Card>( );   //dynamic data type

    for( String p = x.readLine(); p != null ; p = x.readLine()){

        String [] stArray = p.split(",");
        ArrayList.add(new Card( stArray[1], stArray[2])); //new card with name and desc only

    }

    System.out.println(ArrayList.toString());
```

Is the problem with the file or is it with the algorithm?

Comment: use this type of loop`while((String s = br.readLine()) != null)` instead of for loop

Comment: At least one of your lines doesn't have a comma in it. It looks like you have a newline in the middle of one of your rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one line "gains 500 ATK and DEF for each Spell Card you have on the field." that do not contain any `,`. So `stArray[]` has a length of 1.

Other thing: Java arrays are zero base.

And `for( String p = x.readLine(); p != null ; p = x.readLine()){` should be 
`while ((String p = x.readLine())!= null ){`

Answer (score 3):

Your issue here is the 2 consecutive calls to **p=x.readLine()**

```
for( String p = x.readLine(); p != null ; p = x.readLine()){
    ...
}
```

Due to this, 2 lines are read and only 1 is checked for null

You need to change the loop to

```
while (true) {
    String p= x.readLine();
    if (p == null) break;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
while(x.readLine() != null){
---`enter code here`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `x.readLine()`twice in the loop. Hence you are skipping lines while reading.

Better way would be to use **CSVReader** rather than the buffered reader.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fName), ',','"','|');
    List content = reader.readAll();//do not use this if CSV file is large
    String[] row = null;

    for (Object object : content) {
        row = (String[]) object;
        row = Arrays.toString(row).split(",");
        //now you have a row array with length equal to number of columns
    }
```

Here is the link to get CSVReader - [CSVReader Download](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#where-can-I-get-it)

Answer (score 1):

```
while((String p = x.readLine()) != null){

    String [] stArray = p.split(",");
    ArrayList.add(new Card( stArray[0], stArray[1])); //new card with name and desc only

}

System.out.println(ArrayList.toString());
```

this should works

Answer (score 0):

Error is throwing here

```
String [] stArray = p.split(",");
 ArrayList.add(new Card( stArray[1], stArray[2]));
```

Add this condition and check

```
String [] stArray = p.split(",");
ArrayList.add(new Card( stArray[0], stArray[1]));
```

Comment: The answer is the right to life, as sets the right direction.